# Implementing Factory Pattern with reflection

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am implementing factory pattern Here is my factory class:

```
class ProductFactory
{
    private HashMap m_RegisteredProducts = new HashMap();

    public void registerProduct (String productID, Class productClass)
    {
        m_RegisteredProducts.put(productID, productClass);
    }

    public Product createProduct(String productID)
    {
        Class productClass = (Class)m_RegisteredProducts.get(productID);
        Constructor productConstructor = cClass.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
        return (Product)productConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { });
    }
}
```

and here is my concrete class:

```
class OneProduct extends Product
{
    static {
        Factory.instance().registerProduct("ID1",OneProduct.class);
    }
    ...
}
```

My Question:

1. how do I enforce all the concrete implementations to register an ID along with their class object? - Because if the class doesn't register itself like this in the factory then it cant be used.
2. Can't I use an abstract class which requires somehow all its child to send its name and id to the parent, enforcing this constraint? Something like this:

   ```
   public abstract class Product {

       public Product(String name, Class productClass){


       }
   }
   ```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Are you sure you have to use an older version of Java?  Java 8 handles this and does what you want. (Without reflection BTW)

Comment: no, no restrictions on version, I came across upgradations on interfaces in jdk 8, but how to solve this particular thing, I mean enforcing constraint, beats me

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you would write

```
class ProductFactory {
    private final Map<String, Function<String, Product>> m_RegisteredProducts = 
                                                                new HashMap<>();

    public ProductFactory registerProduct (String productID, 
                                 Function<String, Product> productFactory) {
        m_RegisteredProducts.put(productID, productFactory);
        return this;
    }

    public Product createProduct(String productID) {
        return m_RegisteredProducts.get(productID).apply(productID);
    }
}
```

To register

```
static {
    Factory.instance().registerProduct("ID1", OneProduct::new)
                      .registerProduct("ID2", s -> new OneProduct("my" + s));
                      .registerProduct("ID3", s -> { 
                               throw new AssertionError("Never create a " + s); });
}
```

The `OneProduct::new` is much the same as `s -> new OneProduct(s)` or

```
new Function<String, Product>() {
    public Product apply(String s) {
        return new OneProduct(s);
    }
}
```

Note(1): Java 8 will ensure you have a visible `OneProduct(String)` constructor or fail to compile.

Note(2): Java 7 is End of Public Support.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have a few questions:

1. where does the register code go, how does this enforce the contract of registering in factory? 
2. what changes need to be done in the abstract Product class

Answer (score 0):

I think registration from the classes is not a good idea. How would uniqueness of each class id will be determined? In my opinion 'client' classes should be agnostic of the factory and its implementation.

We use a similar factory code which you might be able to use.

```
/*============FACTORY==========*/

Constructor ctor = Class.forName("fullpackage.name." + request.getMethodName()).getConstructor(Param1,Param2);
Runnable obj = (Runnable) ctor.newInstance(Param1,Param2);
Thread t = new Thread(obj);
t.start();
/*=============================*/


/*===========Base Operation Class==============*/
public class Operation implements Runnable {
public Operation(Param1, Param2) {
}
}

/*=============Concrete Operation Class==========*/
public class On extends Operation {
On(Param1, Param2 {
    super(Param1, Param2);
}
@Override
public void run() {
 }
}
/*================================*/
```

Comment: what if in the constructor of the abstract class I check for the uniqueness of the ID, if ID already exists I throw an exception, disallowing an object to be created?